# generalisations of module maps

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

For an algebra $A$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$, consider left modules $E,F$. The two obvious collections of maps to take from $E$ to $F$ are the left module maps ${}_A\mathrm{Hom}(E,F)$ and the linear maps ${}_\mathbb{K}\mathrm{Hom}(E,F)$. However, I am looking for another naturally defined collection of linear maps which are more general than module maps. Ideally these generalised maps should have some sort of categorical structure. They could be dependent on choosing some additional structure on $A$. Is there any such construction in the literature?

This question is motivated by noncommutative geometry, starting with the 1-forms $\Omega^1$ on an algebra. There we can consider the right vector fields $\mathcal{X}^R=\mathrm{Hom}(\Omega^1,A){}_A$ and the left vector fields $\mathcal{X}^L={}_A\mathrm{Hom}(\Omega^1,A)$. However for a star algebra the natural idea of a real (self adjoint) vector field (e.g. considered as a deformation of a smooth manifold) does not fit in either of these cases, but possibly in some intermediate case between being a right and a left module map. In fact the star operation swaps right and left vector fields, but the intersection of these right and left vector fields is too small to be useful.